Typesafe abstract attributes in Python with Pylance
I followed this answer for python 3.3:
class Abstract(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def title(self) -> str: ...

class Concrete(Abstract):
    title = "Test" # pylance error

However in Concrete I get pylance error:
Expression of type "Literal['Test']" cannot be assigned to declared type "property"
"Literal['Test']" is incompatible with "property"

Is it possible to specify abstract attribute in abstract parent class, so it can be overriden by literal value in inheriting class?

This code is relatively(?) fine: you declare a protocol Abstract that, at a minimum, requires read-only title attribute of type str. Your Concrete satisfies that requirement. Furthermore, this is actually a well-known recipe.
The corresponding pyright ticket sheds more light on this problem. The difference is in class access: Abstract means that accessing from a class would yield a property object, but Concrete provides a plain str. This difference may be important in some introspection or metaprogramming cases.
I don't agree with Eric Traut here (will open a ticket later today to expand on this - thanks for bringing this to my attention!), because such behaviour seemingly contradicts with PEP-544 guidelines (using Protocol base instead of ABC in your example doesn't change pyright output):

To define a read-only protocol variable, one can use an (abstract) property.

mypy accepts your code as-is (see recipe above and playground). If you aim to satisfy pyright, you should either override with a property, or add an ignore comment, or look for some workarounds. I would prefer # type: ignore comment solely because I do consider this a typechecker bug, but it's up to you.

Thank you - there is to hope that PEP 729 will resolve these typing issues in sane way.

So there's a couple of different options depending on exact usage. If you want to define an attribute type in an abstract class it can be done like so:
class Abstract(ABC):
    title: str

class Concrete(Abstract):
    title = "test"

This assumes the value of title may change through Concrete, and "test" is just the default value.
It may be however that what you want is a class variable. This would only have it's value set by the concrete class, and not be updated by methods:
from typing import ClassVar

class Abstract(ABC):
    title: ClassVar[str]

class Concrete(Abstract):
    title = "test"

See here for more details. Note that neither of these options enforce the attribute must be overridden as with properties, but this is just the way it works. Hope this helps!
